# Scraping Japanese website using Scrapy but no data in output file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy.  I wanted some data scraped from a Japanese website but when I run the following spider, it won't show any data on the exported file.  Can someone help me please.

Exporting to csv format doesn't show any results in the shell either, just `[]`.

Here is my code.

```
import scrapy

class suumotest(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "testsecond"

    start_urls = [
        'https://suumo.jp/jj/chintai/ichiran/FR301FC005/?tc=0401303&tc=0401304&ar=010&bs=040'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # for following property link
        for href in response.css('.property_inner-title+a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_info)



    # defining parser to extract data   
    def parse_info(self, response):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()

        yield {
          'Title': extract_with_css('h1.section_title::text'),
          'Fee': extract_with_css('td.detailinfo-col--01 span.detailvalue-item-accent::text'),
          'Fee Descrition': extract_with_css('td.detailinfo-col--01 span.detailvalue-item-text::text'),
          'Prop Description': extract_with_css('td.detailinfo-col--03::text'),
          'Prop Address': extract_with_css('td.detailinfo-col--04::text'),
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first css selector in `parse` method is faulty here:

```
response.css('.property_inner-title+a::attr(href)').extract()
```

`+` is the fault here. Just replace it with a space, like:

```
response.css('.property_inner-title a::attr(href)').extract()
```

Another issue is in your defined `extract_with_css()` function:

```
def parse_info(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()
```

The problem here is that `extract_first()` will return `None` by default if no values are found and `.strip()` is a function of `string` base class, since you're not getting a string this will throw an error.
To fix that you can set default value to `extract_first` to be an empty string instead:

```
def parse_info(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first('').strip()
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. Now Getting an error 'spider_exception/AttributeError :30' @Granitosaurus

Comment: @bassamfarooq can you post a log? seems like now you're having a  different problem entirely. You can produce a log via `scrapy crawl myspider &> output.log` command on linux. Or at least copy the whole traceback error message you're getting.

Comment: @bassamfarooq I've tried running your spider and found the error, see the my edit.

Comment: Ok i just removed strip() part from the code on line 22. and now it scrapes some data but just the title. and when am exporting it to a csv file. The data is nt shown properly in excel but shows up correctly in notepad++.

Comment: @bassamfarooq see my edit to the answer. Either way you get empty data because some of css selectors don't find anything, try refining them by inspecting the page source tree with javascript disabled.

Comment: Thank You @Granitosaurus that helped a bit. But Still having some problems.
1. fee descrition ,prop address and prop description fields are not getting populated.

Comment: @bassamfarooq well I've answered your question, if you need help fixing your css selector values I suggest opening up a new issue since this is not very related to your current issue.

Comment: Thanks @Granitosaurus . Looking into the code. Will try to refine more. As per your suggestion tried refining the css selectors and found some issues. Thanks again for the quick help.